# What are the default permissions on the Applications folder in OS X supposed to be?

Tags: folders, permission, settings, virtualbox, defaults

I was trying to run VirtualBox on OS X when I got the error:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine tinyXP.
Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SUPLIB_WORLD_WRITABLE).
Unknown error creating VM (VERR_SUPLIB_WORLD_WRITABLE).
```

[image]

According to this article http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/8410, it is because the permissions on my `/Applications` folder are too broad. I checked, and I was actually very surprised to learn that the folder was in fact world-readable / world-writable.

```
drwxrwxrwx+ 164 root  admin      5576 Jun 26 22:27 Applications
```

So before I go changing them, I'm wondering if that is normal or if somehow they got changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not normal - I have

```
drwxrwxr-x+ 73 root     admin         2482 24 Jun 09:28 Applications/
```

There is a option in Disk Utility.app to repair permissions which should change the Applications directory and others back.

Comment: +1 for repairing permissions with Disk Utility. I do that once a month as a matter of course.

Comment: That's great. Hundreds of things out of wack on mine. Thanks!

Comment: [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/245756/87494) explains how to run the repair permissions util from the Terminal since it was removed from Disk Utility in El Capitan.