# Applications folder not owned by root, cannot change it

Tags: applications, virtualbox

After a recent run of Migration Assistant from an old MacBook to a new one, my Applications folder is owned by my normal user account rather than by root.  This prevents VirtualBox from functioning (see [here](http://mirabedini.com/blog/?p=563), for example).

Attempting to fix the permissions with a simple `sudo chown root /Applications` gives the error `chown: /Applications: Operation not permitted`.  This is pleasantly vague, and the Internet assures me that [there may be many causes](https://superuser.com/questions/279235/why-does-chown-report-operation-not-permitted-on-os-x).  (I had other sources I could cite, but I'm new to this site, and thus can only post up to 2 links.)

I do not wish to just start removing flags carelessly from `/Applications`, so I've done some investigating instead.  Here's what's NOT the problem:

- File flags:  Only the `sunlnk` flag is set, which prevents `/Applications` from being deleted.  Seems entirely appropriate for `/Applications`, so I think there's no problem there.  In particular, the `suchg` flag is NOT set.
- SIP:  That feature doesn't govern the `/Applications` folder, as far as my reading indicates.  So I don't think I need to do any of the "Recovery Mode" business to disable SIP.
- ACLs:  The only one reported by `ls -le` is `group:everyone deny delete` which, again, seems entirely appropriate, and doesn't seem to have anything to do with `chown`.

So that's what's NOT the problem (I think).  But I don't know what IS the problem.

Comment: Is `sunlnk` a valid flag? I don't have el capitan but you can check in `man 2 chflags`.

Comment: I can confirm `sunlnk` on the /Applications folder on El Capitan.

Comment: Yes, `sunlnk` means you that the "unlnk" (unlink = delete) operation is "s"et (the flag is on, not off).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I was wrong to assume that SIP could not be at fault.  When trying the operation with SIP disabled, it worked.  I also needed to `chmod` /Applications to have permissions 755 (was 775) before VirtualBox would be happy, but that, too, was doable with SIP disabled.  All working now.

Thanks to a discussion ranklord and I had in some comments above, and then in the chat for this question, for figuring this out.

Answer (score 4):

Funnily enough this is a perfect example of one of the few situations where repairing disk permissions is actually called for.

Unfortunately the Repair Disk Permissions option has been removed from Disk Utility in El Capitan.

However you can still do it from the command line.

In Terminal run the following command to find out which permissions are incorrect.

> sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --verify --standard-pkgs /

And run the following command to repair the permissions.

> sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs --volume /

More information here: http://osxdaily.com/2015/11/04/verify-repair-permissions-mac-os-x/

Comment: Thank you, but this did not succeed.  While this did repair a lot of things, it also gave a lot of "Error 1: Operation not permitted" messages.  At the end, my Applications folder is still owned by my main user, not root.

Answer (score 0):

What shows your 'Get Info' command (right-click on Applications folder) and can you change owner from there?

[image]

Comment: My UI does not look like yours.  I do not have a "Permissions" section, just a "Sharing & Permissions" section with a different UI, like this: https://ibin.co/2npqPDIByBvN.png

Comment: Is the user under which you are working in admin group then?

Comment: No, I seem to be in the "staff" group.

Comment: Then you need to check permissions for this group. Could be that you don't have enough rights to change ownership of the folder. Or add yourself to admins group

Comment: The group for the `/Applications` folder is currently `staff`.  That's the folder that matters, right (not its containing folder)?

Comment: Hmm... May be we have close encounter with [SIP](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html) here? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42396/discussion-between-nathan-and-ranklord).

Comment: Beside the topic of this post: what did you do/install to make the "Get Info" panel look like this?